# Is correct to find with "half days" -mtime +2.5 -delete?

Tags: find

I'm wondering if is correct to find with half days like this
-mtime +2.5 -delete     for 2 and a half days

LE: there are any dangers in using this?

Comment: No, except that you have to be aware of how `find` is rounding.

Answer (score 0):

check the -mmin.

```
   -mmin n
          Fileâs data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

> -mmin +3600

Comment: Surely `-mmin -$((12*60))` (`720`)?